# Remove keywords that not belongs to a city name Dictionary text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I have a Dictionary text file which contains the names/keywords of the cities of the world and these keywords are almost `3,00,000`, But it also have many of the irrelevant keywords e.g. `this , is , on ,Over , Old , It , a , From etc .....`

You can see that these keywords are not belongs to any of the city name, So How can I remove all those keywords which are not belongs to city name.

I have no idea what should I do.

**Is there any Solution to Solve this problem ??**
Some sample data is here

```
Japon
Bagpat
Jharda
Kilbrin
This
Großköllnbach
Sighetu Silvaniei
Schweich
Colinet
Leskovec
Trizay
Kilen
Le Perreux
Give
Combourg
Migliaro
Stawki
Kingham
```

Comment: You need to share subset of the data  so we will be able to understand the data structure.

Comment: @balderman I have Edited the question

Comment: The data you shared looks like a simple txt file - not a dict. In order to do a cleanup you need to prepare a list of words that you want to skip (Over old...), read the file line and check if the 'current' word is in the list you prepared. If it is - you want to skip over this word.

Comment: yes you are right , this is text file and your solution is right,, but I don't know how many and which words are non-city names in the file so How can I remove non-city names from the file ?

Comment: I mention some example words in the question which i saw but file contain 3,00,000 records or lines ,I dont know which words are not city names ,so what should I do ?

Comment: You have 3 options. a) get a list of world cities b) compose a list of non city names. c) find an API that will let you know if a word is name of a city or not (Google Maps?)

Comment: https://github.com/datasets/world-cities/blob/master/data/world-cities.csv cities DB

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare an irrelevant bag of words to detect them, then you can remove these irrelevant words.

If you do not know which words are non-city names in your file, you should try to analyze and find similarities between these irrelevant words.